# How converter null to ImageNull.jpg

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

This code not work?
column don't show

```
<sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                    <Image Tag="{Binding photo}" MaxHeight="50">
                                        <Image.Source>
                                            <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding photo, Converter={StaticResource ConvertNullImageKey}}" />
                                        </Image.Source>
                                    </Image>
                                </DataTemplate>
                        </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Converter:

```
public class ConvertNullImage : IValueConverter
        {

            public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
            {
                var image = new BitmapImage();
                try
                {
                    image = new BitmapImage(new Uri(value.ToString()));
                    return image;
                }
                catch { return new BitmapImage(new Uri("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1c/No-Symbol.png")); }
            }

            public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
                                      CultureInfo culture)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are currently doing is taking an existing `BitmapImage` and trying to assign another `BitmapImage` to its `UriSource`.  Have you tried this:-

```
<Image Tag="{Binding photo}" MaxHeight="50" Source="{Binding photo, Converter={StaticResource ConvertNullImageKey}}" />
```